# Using a Wildcard in Quarkus Config path for IfBuildProperty

Tags: conditional-statements, config, quarkus

I'm currently trying to only create a bean for my class if a property is set in my quarkus application.yaml config. I can get this to work just fine when I build my application locally, however when I deploy my service with rancher my config variable path is prepended with another value, making me think my IfBuildProperty Annotation can no longer find my property as the path is not exact anymore. Is there no way to set a wildcard or prefix to my config path in my annotation to rectify this?

Locally Working

```
@IfBuildProperty(name = "user.environment", stringValue = "true")
Local Config
user:
  environment: true
non-user:
  environment: false
```

Config setup in my rancher cluster

```
MyApplication:
  user:
    environment: true
  non-user:
    environment: false
```

I have also tried making my user/non-user classes @Dependent and then using a wrapper class that pulls config values with @ConfigMapping(prefix = "user"), and this works to get the value fine, but when I made a method to do an @Produces and decide which environment to use, the beans were already created for both @Dependent classes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We don't have a feature like this, but you are welcome to request it on a Github issue